# Trying to Duplicate Excel Pivot Function Via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to do something equivalent to an Excel pivot table in Python? What I'm looking for is to take data that says, effectively the following (and please excuse my lack of formatting, I have been awake and working on this for something like 14 hours now):

[image]

And make it look like this:

[image]

I'm obviously looking at multiple rows of sales for each category and year. I definitely need them totalled. I'm sure there's a way to do this without iterating through each and every line and keeping running totals of each possible combination, but for the life of me, I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas pivot table.

See the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Category":["Furniture", "Furniture", "Clothing", "Shoes", "Furniture", "Clothing", "Shoes"],
                   "Year":[2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010],
                   "Sales":[50000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 70000, 30000, 10000]})
    
pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'Category', columns = 'Year', values = 'Sales')
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. LOL I don't know how I missed it, but I really do appreciate the help.